# Почему интерпретатор не может понять значение переменной? Ошибка: local variable 'el' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, массивы

```
for el in vozmozhnye_hody:
            for el1 in vozmozhnye_hody:
                if vozmozhnye_hody.index(el)!=vozmozhnye_hody.index(el1):
                    if len(el)<=len(el1):
                        for i in range(len(el1) - len(el)):
                            if el1[i:i+len(el)] == el:
                                del el
```

Выдает ошибку:

> ```
> Exception in Tkinter callback
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "D:\Install\python\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1537, in __call__
>     return self.func(*args)
>   File "D:\Install\python\shashki1.py", line 74, in obrabotchik_button1
>     aktivator_shashki(x,y)
>   File "D:\Install\python\shashki1.py", line 87, in aktivator_shashki
>     bit_shashku()
>   File "D:\Install\python\shashki1.py", line 114, in bit_shashku
>     if el1[i:i+len(el)] == el:
> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'el' referenced before assignment
> что не так?
> ```

Comment: Никогда не используйте в качестве идентификаторов русские слова, написанные латинскими буквами. Используйте английские слова.

Comment: Никогда не говорите «никогда» :-)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow и полчаса гуглишь как назвать какое-нибудь бухгалтерское слово по английски.

Comment: @eri Полчаса гуглишь, и всю оставшуюся жизнь код программы будет читаемым .

Answer (score 1):

После того как вы удалили переменную `el` во внутреннем цикле:

```
del el
```

в следующей строке (в последующих итерациях) вы уже обращаетесь к несуществующей и необъявленной переменной `el`:

```
if el1[i:i+len(el)] == el:
```

Comment: т.е. написать после del el   break?

Comment: @Макс, для начала стоит объяснить что вы пытаетесь сделать в этом блоке кода... ;) PS `break` выбросит вас только из текущего цикла, а они у вас вложенные

Comment: спасибо я понял ошибку и уже понял как исправить

Comment: @Макс, по-моему, вы пытаетесь изобрести велосипед - почитайте о `Combinatoric iterators` функциях из модуля [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html)

Comment: блин там все на английском написано и страницу не переводит

Comment: <off topic> Выучив английский хотя бы в объеме, достаточном для понимания технической документации, вы несказанно облегчите свое дальнейшее общение с языками программирования и с IT в целом</off topic>. [`Google Translate` худо-бедно переводит официальную документацию](https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?depth=1&rurl=translate.google.com&sl=en&sp=nmt4&tl=ru&u=https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html&xid=25657,15700022,15700124,15700186,15700191,15700201,15700237,15700242,15700248&usg=ALkJrhi6CE73vs8h0J19Er8e6YIom7cYWQ#itertools.combinations)